# Do you hear "snarky", to imply some level of wry, off-the-cuff, perhaps mildly acerbic, humor?

Tags: meaning

People I know use the word that way, but most online definitions put it, I'd say more in the range between acerbic and acid, with no humor.  MW does have a second "irreverent" sense, that's also pretty good for how I have it, but if that's not the common interpretation I'd better make some changes...

Comment: Yes, but I also hear it (and use it) to mean a thorny situation such as bad traffic, a complicated work problem or even a bad attitude - "his response seemed rather snarky - I wonder what's eating him?"

Comment: @KristinaLopez Thank you.  I've never heard it used for anything but human responses, so that's new. As Sven Yargs says, it's clearly being refitted, evolving fast.  I won't use it in anything but personal conversation now, so between yours and his I've gotten what I came for. Thanks to you both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My impression is that people use *snarky* to mean everything from "mean-spirited" or "rude" (no hint of humor) to "sarcastic" (humor with a hostile edge). I don't associate the word with merely wry or off-the-cuff humor. But let's see how various reference works define the term.

From *Merriam-Webster's Collegiate Dictionary*, eleventh edition (2003):

> **snarky** *adj* [dial. *snark* to annoy, perh(aps) alter(ation) of *nark* to irritate] (1906) **1 :** CROTCHETY, SNAPPISH **2 :** sarcastic, impertinent, or irreverent in tone or manner {*snarky* lyrics}

The Eleventh Edition's definition 2 is new to that edition. The Tenth Edition (1993) has only the "CROTCHETY, SNAPPISH" definition, and the Ninth Edition (1989) has no entry for *snarky*.

From *The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language*, fourth edition (2000):

> **snarky** *adj Slang* Irritable or short-tempered; irascible. [From dialectal *snark*, to nag, from *snark*, *snork*, to snore, snort, from Dutch or Low German *snorken*, of imitative origin.]

The third edition of the AHDEL has no entry for *snarky*.

From Barbara Kipfer & Robert Chapman, *Dictionary of American Slang*, fourth edition (2007):

> **snarky** ***adj*** Irritable, touchy : *She's just in a snarky mood, that's all* [—Noel B B Gerson]*/ a snarky, no-illusions, but far-from-hopeless comedy* [—*Ms* magazine] [1906+; fr British dialect snark, "to fin fault, complain," fr the basic sense "snort, snore"; of echoic origin, with cognates in many Germanic languages]

The third edition of Kipfer & Chapman (1995) has the same entry for *snarky* as the fourth edition (except that it also identifies the sources of the two included examples).

A very different—and presumably obsolete—meaning appears in the first edition of the *Dictionary of American Slang*, however. From Harold Wentworth & Stuart Flexner, *Dictionary of American Slang* (1960):

> **snarky snorky** *adj.* Elegant; ritzy. 1941: "It's a snarky one [automobile]—a super-dooper." Radio, *Fibber McGee*, Nov. 18. *Dial*.

Clearly, *snarky* is a rapidly evolving term, and dictionaries have only recently begun to come to grips with it. The second definition in the Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary and the second example in Kipfer & Chapman seem to support your suggestion that the word can refer to "mildly acerbic humor." But dictionaries haven't yet caught up with the more benign sense of "wry [or] off-the-cuff" humor that you suggest—if indeed a significant number of users have that meaning in mind.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't heard anyone using the older senses I found, seems local culture is using a milder form than found elsewhere -- I've never heard it used for responses lacking all humor.  Those are just "mean".  I suppose you could accurately say there's sarcasm in every use I've heard, but there's no acerbity in friendly needling.  And I can see how that'd be a local usage not likely to spread. Anyway, thanks for the wider survey than I'd taken.

Answer (score 2):

'Snorky' around here (Sussex,Uk) is a mild rebuke for someone who is being irascible and rude. It's a minor criticism. Nice word . Personally not heard 'snarky' variant for many years.